# How can I get jquery datepicker to work on cloned rows?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have looked over many pages helping with the jquery datepicker not being functional on cloned rows, but I can't seem to translate any of the suggestions I found to my particular case. Here's the Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/BE5Lr/2893/
 Any advice would be appreciated.

```
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});

var i = 1;
$("button").click(function() {
  $("table tr:first").clone().removeClass('hasDatepicker').find("input").each(function() {
    $(this).attr({
      'id': function(_, id) { return id + i },
      'name': function(_, name) { return name + i },
      'value': ''

    });
  }).end().appendTo("table");

  i++;

});
```

Comment: I personally would not clone the rows, and instead generate a new row based on an htmlstring template.

Comment: Why isn't your button click handler inside the dom ready handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ClaudioZ had it almost right...

Adding a mydatepickers (or whatever name you choose) **class** is necessary.

But before you re-initialize the datepicker elements in the click event, *you must first detach the datepicker fields before cloning the row (i.e. inside the click handler).*

As Russell G explains [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419996/how-to-clone-a-table-row-with-a-datepicker-using-jquery), this is probably because the datepicker object thinks it has already been initialized throughout the DOM and aborts.

Finally, after cloning the row, you re-initialize them all.

[See jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/RG4gP/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".mydatepickers").datepicker();

    //$( ".mydatepickers" ).datepicker();
    $( "input.mydatepickers" ).on('click', function() {
        //alert('hi'); 
        $(this).datepicker();
    });;

    var i = 1;
    $("button").on('click', function() {
        $('.mydatepickers').datepicker('destroy');
        myTr = $("table tr:first").clone().appendTo("table");
        myTr.removeClass('hasDatepicker').find("input").each(function() {
            $(this).attr({
                'id': function(_, id) { return id + i },
                'name': function(_, name) { return name + i },
                'value': ''
            });
        });
        //myTr.find('input[id^="datep"]').addClass("mydatepickers");
         $(".mydatepickers").datepicker();
        i++;
        alert('Current value of i is: ' + i);
    });

}); //END $(document).ready()
```

Comment: That got it! Thank you very much gibberish!

Answer (score 2):

Call $(...).datepicker() again in the click event.

Add a class "mydatepickers" to the input

$(".mydatepickers").datepicker();

Comment: Your solution doesn't seem to work... Have I missed something?  [See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svu4d/)

Comment: The solution of Aarons at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877427/jquery-datepicker-method-not-working-on-duplicate-element) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

How it Works:

Need to remove the class **hasDatepickerfrom** the cloned elements,because this is what is preventing the datepicker from getting attached to the specific element.

Need to remove the **id** attribute from each of the cloned elements else .datepicker() will assume that datepicker is added to this element.

After that call .**datepicker**() on cloned element.

```
newNode.find('.test').each(function() {
   $(this).removeAttr('id').removeClass('hasDatepicker');
   $(this).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', minDate: 0, autoclose: true,});
});
```